# trying to add an actionlistener

Tags: jsf, listener

Im trying to add an actionlistener to MenuItem primefaces component

```
itemLogout.addActionListener(new ActionListenerManagedBean());
```

And in the ActionListenerManagedBean I use :

```
public class ActionListenerManagedBean implements ActionListener {


    public ActionListenerManagedBean() {
        super();

    }

    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionEvent arg0) throws AbortProcessingException {
        System.out.println("Test Action Listener called..");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == "aa"){
    } 
    }
}
```

But not happens when I click on logout item menu.

Would you help me please ? thanks in advance...

Comment: Please elaborate "not happens" in developer's terms instead of enduser's terms. What exactly does not happen? Sending of the HTTP request? Retrieving of the HTTP request? Restoring the JSF view? Decoding and applying the request parameters? Identifying the button component being clicked? Queueing the action event? Advancing to the invoke application phase? Firing the action event? Invoking the action listener method? Passing the `if` block inside the method?

Comment: Note that the current answer naively only assumes the last aspect. I however think that JSF failed to identify the button component being clicked. A common starter's mistake in creating dynamic components is namely that they forgot to set the component ID. It'd be more helpful if you show the code in flavor of an SSCCE instead of randomly selected parts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `e.getSource() == "aa"` should be `e.getSource() == itemLogout`.

Basically `e.getSource()` Returns the object where the action was invoked on.

I am assuming that ActionListenerManagedBean is a inner class.

Comment: I admit that OP's code is far from complete, but I just wanted to warn that [the JSF `ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/ActionListener.html) doesn't specify the `actionPerformed` method, but instead the `processAction` method. So, when being used as JSF action listener, the `actionPerformed` method is **never** invoked. It's instead the `processAction` method. The `actionPerformed` is likely a leftover of an accidental import of [the AWT `ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html). Also note the `@Override`

Comment: Im not using an inner class and the processAction is not invoked. sorry for my english

Comment: MenuItem itemLogout = new MenuItem();
  itemLogout.setValue("Sair");
  itemLogout.setId("itemLogout");
  itemLogout.addActionListener(new ActionListenerManagedBean());
  itemLogout.setOutcome("logout");
  menuModel.addMenuItem(itemLogout);